# How to integrate Rancher Kubernetes cluster with Sysdig inspect

Tags: kubernetes, inspect, rancher, sysdig

Any ideas to integrate the Kubernetes cluster on rancher with Sysdig Inspect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean by 'integrate', but it's pretty straightforward.

Install [Sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) on all your Kubernetes nodes then run it and create capture files.  Grab those capture files and load them up on [Sysdig inspect](https://github.com/draios/sysdig-inspect)

If you'd like a more seamless integration where the capture files are stored in something like [S3](https://sysdigdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/Platform/pages/206569555/Storage+Configure+AWS+Capture+File+Storage+Optional) and examine them from there, you will have to go with [Sysdig's paid product](https://sysdig.com/products/monitor/).

Comment: I installed sysdig on my nodes. I am looking for a process where I can automate the pushing of capture files to sysdig inspect. Is there any process to do it?